# overloading resolution, cpp

Tags: c++, overloading, resolution

I understand that if there are several function with the same name and same number of parameters the compiler is trying to find the best match (am I right so far?)

What I don't understand is the difference between type promotion and type conversion.

Say I have this function decleration: `void foo (double x)` and then inside main:

```
int x = 5;
foo(x);
```

Is that considered conversion or promotion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type promotion is special case of type conversion.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion#Type_promotion

Answer (score -3):

Your example wont work

you would need to have 2 methods for overloading

1.) void foo(double x){method code} and

2.) void foo(int x){method code}

Then when you run the code

int x = 5;

foo(5)

The compiler or run time environment knows which method to call based on the input type you passed in.

If I want to convert an int into a double that is different. I am not sure what language you are using but in Java you would do the conversion using type casting

this is type casting and will convert a double to an int.  You will loose the decimal part if there is one.

double d = 5;
int i = (int)d;

I think this is what you are asking.  If not please clarify a little

Comment: the language is C++, and the example _does_ work, the question is about terminology.